# Update plot matplotlib tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following piece of code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()

figure = Figure()
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure,master=root) 

axes = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axes.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])

figure_to_pack_d1 = figure_canvas.get_tk_widget()
figure_to_pack_d1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

def plot_axes():
    axes.clear()
    axes.plot([1,2,3],[3,2,1])
tk.Button(root,command=plot_axes,text="Update plot").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It's supposed to generate a simple GUI with a matplotlib plot and a button (done correctly). When you press the button, the plot should change. When the button gets pressed, seems that nothing is happening, but if you *force* to update the window (changing it's size) it gets updated correctly. Is there any way to update the plot immediatly after the button is pressed? I've tried some methods like *root.update()*, *axes.update({})*, *figure.canvas.flush_events()*... But none of them worked.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finnaly able to find my own answer. The actual way to *update* the plot is with de command:

```
figure_canvas.draw()
```

So, the script looks like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()

figure = Figure()
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure,master=root) 

axes = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axes.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])

figure_to_pack_d1 = figure_canvas.get_tk_widget()
figure_to_pack_d1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

def plot_axes():
    axes.clear()
    axes.plot([1,2,3],[3,2,1])
    figure_canvas.draw()
tk.Button(root,command=plot_axes,text="Update plot").pack()

root.mainloop()
```